# Preventing NetworkManager from bring certain network interfaces 'up' by default

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there a way to specifically control which networking interfaces are brought online automatically by NetworkManager when I login?  I have two wifi cards, one of which doesn't work, and I need to be able to specify "Don't automatically bring up wlan0" so that my wifi works and is stable.

Right now, I disable the interface by doing `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` to manually bring down the interface after login, but I'd like to not have to do that step.

---

The system this is primarily going to be used on is a Precise (12.04) system, but I would also like this to work with later versions as well.

Comment: Why not blacklist the driver for wlan0?

Comment: @chili555 because at times I may need to use that interface and it needs to be readily available in the event the other one won't work for the network(s) I use.  Which happens sometimes because of MAC address restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above exit 0 add the following:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Now the computer will boot with wlan0 down. If you later need to use it, take down wlan1 and bring up wlan0:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: *facepalm* I forgot all about /etc/rc.local.  But I've tried a similar thing, using a TTY before logging in and doing `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` but after I logged in, the network interface was back up, because Network Manager (part of the GUI) brought it back up on its own.  I'm not sure the method here will work, based on my tests.  I'll test this at next reboot though, and we'll see if this answer works or not.  (You still get an upvote!)